# View a powerpoint created on a Mac with TIFF images on Windows

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, tiff

I have a few powerpoint lectures that contain TIFF files that cannot be displayed on Windows. The images are blank except for the words "Quicktime and a TIFF (Uncompressed) decompressor are needed to see this picture". It is my understanding that this is as a result of the powerpoint being created on a Mac. Since I have no access to a Mac, is there any way to convert it? Any programs that run on Windows which would allow me to view the slides with the images would also work.

Comment: What happens if you install quicktime on windows. Do you have this possibility (i.e. or do you have to show the presentation on a borrowed computer).

Comment: I strongly suppose that. You can choose the format when you saves the presentation. What happens if you store the presentation in a different format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing QT on Windows won't help unless things have changed in the latest Windows versions.

This problem occurs when you copy/paste pictures into Mac PowerPoint.  The fix:  Don't Do That.  Use PowerPoint's Insert Picture, From File command to bring the pictures in.

Unfortunately, you have to do this on the Mac in the first place.  You can't fix it on the PC, so you'll have to go back to the presentation's author for a fix.